# KeyPressed in textbox not working

Tags: c#-4.0, key

I tried to get the code below working, but to no avail.

I have to make a login window, and except from the `Log in` button I want by pressing the `Enter` key in password textbox the result to be the same. C# 2010.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int ok=0;
            if (textBox1.Text == "administrator" && textBox2.Text == "administrator")
            {
                ok = 1;
                this.Hide();
                Admin admin = new Admin();
                admin.ShowDialog();
            }
            if (textBox1.Text == "jucator" && textBox2.Text == "jucator")
            {
                ok = 1;
                this.Hide();
            }
            if (ok == 0)
            {
                label2.Text = "nume user sau parola incorecta";
                label2.Visible = true;
            }

        }
        private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                button1_Click(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the **KeyUp** *event* It's more reliable in you case.
Then check for the pressed key. 
e.g.:

```
    private void textBox2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            //DoLogin... in your case it would be 
            button1_Click(null,null);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }
```

---

On a side note: I really discourage you to use that **Log In** method, comparing strings to a hardcoded strings is really a waste, there're better scenarios specially in an environment where you have multiple users *Otherwise why would you require a login?*